# How to retrieve tag plain text inside a nested tag

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML page and I want to retrieve a tag's plain text which is in another tag using JavaScript.

```
<div id="article_content">
    <p>paragraph 1 </p>
    <p>paragraph 2 </p>
    <p>paragraph 3 </p>
</div>
```

So basically I want to retrieve all of the `<p>` plain text. Please help

On a side note: I'm incorporating my JavaScript in android studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `.textContent` of the parent node to get the text.

```js
alert(document.querySelector('#article_content').textContent)
```

```html
<div id="article_content">
    <p>paragraph 1 </p>
    <p>paragraph 2 </p>
    <p>paragraph 3 </p>
</div>
```

Comment: I forgot to mention detail,this javascript is inside android studio. So when I place this inside my code  `webview.loadUrl("javascript:console.log('Test :- ' + document.querySelector('#article_content').textContent);"); ` it gives me this ApplicationContext is null in ApplicationStatus

Answer (score -1):

You can try using:

```
arr = document.getElementById("article_content").children;

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
    console.log(arr[i].innerHTML);
```

**document.getElementById("article_content")** returns an object representing the tag with id "article_content".

**.children** member function returns all the elements of the tag with id "article_content" as an HTML collection.

Then use **.innerHTML** to access the content of the `<p>` tags inside the div with id "article_content".

More useful information on this can be found at http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_all.asp

Answer (score -1):

You can use `$("#article_content").text()` to get the contents as text.